# How can I add scrollbar vertical in the modal dialog on the vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, modal-dialog, vue-component, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-dialog
            v-for='foo, k in foos' :key='foo.id'
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            transition="scale-transition"
            :return-value.sync="foo.date"
            min-width="290px" 
            v-model="modal[k]"
            :ref="'dialog' + k"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="success" dark v-on="on">call date {{foo.id}} {{ foo.date }}</v-btn>
            </template>

            <v-row justify="center">
            <v-date-picker v-model="foo.date" @input="changeHours">
                <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal[k] = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs['dialog' + k][0].save(foo.date)">OK</v-btn>
            </v-date-picker>
            <v-slide-y-transition>
            <v-col cols=2 v-show="foo.date !== null"  :style="{'background-color':'white'}">
              <template v-for="allowedTime in allowedTimes">
                <v-btn
                  @click="setTime(allowedTime)"
                  class="my-2"
                  :outlined="allowedTime !== time"
                  block
                  x-large
                  color="primary"
                >{{ allowedTime }}</v-btn>
              </template>
            </v-col>
            </v-slide-y-transition>
            </v-row>
        </v-dialog>    
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

demo is like this :

https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/YzzwYZq

I want when there is a lot of time, scrollbar automatically appears in the modal dialog

how can i do it?

Comment: Already scrollbar is available in modal dialog. What exactly you want here?

Comment: @chans there is no. you try to check in my codepen

Comment: add this chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200990/how-can-i-add-scrollbar-vertical-in-the-modal-dialog-on-the-vuetify

Comment: I've added a screenshot in chat room

Comment: @chans I can not access the chat room because my reputation under 20

Comment: Now you can able to access

Comment: @chans yes. but I want a scrollbar inside the modal. not outside. it looked untidy

Comment: Here is the working codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/GRRqLyp

Comment: @chans it looks like a datepicker in modal. can you make it look just a datepicker? so it looks neat

Answer (score 0):

Added a v-flex wrapper around content area inside v-dialog, then set width limit for row to restrict, Now its working as expected

add css

```
.row {
margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Updated codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/GRRqLyp

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-dialog
            v-for='foo, k in foos' :key='foo.id'
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            transition="scale-transition"
            :return-value.sync="foo.date"
            v-model="modal[k]"
             max-width="390px"
            :ref="'dialog' + k"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="success" dark v-on="on">call date {{foo.id}} {{ foo.date }}</v-btn>
            </template>

          <v-flex row-wrap justify-center>
            <v-row>
            <v-date-picker v-model="foo.date" @input="changeHours">
                <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal[k] = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs['dialog' + k][0].save(foo.date)">OK</v-btn>
            </v-date-picker>
            <v-col class="col-3" v-show="foo.date !== null"  :style="{'background-color':'white'}">
              <template v-for="allowedTime in allowedTimes">
                <div>
                <v-btn
                  @click="setTime(allowedTime)"
                  class="my-2"
                  :outlined="allowedTime !== time"
                         large
                  color="primary"
                       >{{ allowedTime }}</v-btn></div>
              </template>
            </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-flex>
        </v-dialog>    
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: can it be made dynamic? look at this: https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/GRRjXOK. if I change the watch, it doesn't look neat

Comment: Yes you can set max-width dynamically based on the length of length 390px or 440px  here is the codepen https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/RwwGYBb

Comment: Okay, thanks. How do I set the height of the modal? I want to place the cancel button and the ok button a little bit up. which is now too far down. How can I  do it?

Comment: Great. Thanks. I want to ask again :) Can the scrollbar be made like this : https://postimg.cc/Wd5h8QQ4? it looks neater